# Posting array of objects to ASP.NET MVC Controller get 403 error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post an array of objects to MVC controller, and when the size of the array is less than 30ish records the posting works fine.  However, when the array size is over that number, it would return 403 error.  The code works when it was tested in VS 2019 in debug mode no matter how big the array is, but it gives 403 error when it runs on IIS.

I've tried to make the following changes in the environment base on my search here with no avail:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="50000" /> // changed to even higher number like 150000
```

```
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="40960" targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10485760" /> // changed to even higher number like 50000000
```

Here is the jquery post method:

```
var progress = $.connection.progressHub;
progress.client.addProgress = function (message, percentage) {
   UpdateProgress(message, percentage);
};
var params = '';
var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
var cnt = grid.dataSource.data().length;

for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    var model = grid.dataItem("tbody tr:eq(" + i + ")");
    params += "&models[" + i + "].ItemId=" + model.ItemId;
    params += "&models[" + i + "].ItemNo=" + model.ItemNo;
    params += "&models[" + i + "].Price=" + model.Price;
    params += "&models[" + i + "].SalesPrice=" + model.SalesPrice;
    params += "&models[" + i + "].Qty=" + model.Qty;
    params += "&models[" + i + "].CreatedDate=" + model.CreatedDate;
    params += "&models[" + i + "].Amount=" + model.Amount;
    params += "&models[" + i + "].OrderId=" + model.OrderId;
}

if (params != '') {
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $.post('@(Url.Action("SomeFunction", "Controller", new { area = "Sales" }))', params, function (result) {

            Messager.Success('Success');
            window.location.reload();
        });
   });
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult SomeFunction([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<OrderitemViewModel> viewModel)
        {
            var cnt = 0;
            var totalCount = viewModel.Count();

            if (viewModel != null)
            {
                foreach (var master in viewModel)
                {
                    _svc.DetailFunction(request, master);
                    ProgressHub.SendProgress("Sync in progress...", ++cnt, totalCount);
                }
            }
            return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my issue is related to AWS WAF blocking the request.

The specific rule group to change is in

```
AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet
```

and the rule I have to override is

```
SizeRestrictions_BODY
```